# Blender keeps wanting to use my CPU instead of my assigned gpu

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

So just to start off, I have checked that all the hardware I have is compatible with one another, and I have no problem running video games which use up my gpu and cpu in unison. However, when it comes to blender, even tho I set my device to GPU COMPUTE and i am on feature set: supported (ive tried experimental), whenever I render, I can see that my cpu sky rockets to 100% load! and zero gpu. I dont understand why this is happening. I have updated my drivers for my gpu and re-installed blender. I really dont know what to do! It keeps crashing after about 30 or so minutes but it isnt a continues crash. Sometimes, it renders completely... 
Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!
Yokubo~

Comment: how does your GPU settings in the preferences looks like? (Preferences > System)

Comment: Here is what it looks like: https://imgur.com/a/JJl7T

Answer (score 1):

FIXED! I had to enable CUDA in my user preferences under |system| in "cycles compute device.
Thanks for answering tho! I would not have looked as closely if it was not for you.